# fillMaxHeight() inside Row

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

My question is related to this one: [How to achieve this layout in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043704/how-to-achieve-this-layout-in-jetpack-compose)

I have this code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestUi() {
    Row {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Yellow)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    
        Image(imageVector = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
    }
}
```

I expected to get this:

[image: Expected result]

But I got this instead:

[image: Actual result]

How can I get the Box to fill all the available height without affecting the height of the Row?

I know I could use a ConstraintLayout to solve this, but it seems too much for such a simple use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me  `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)`

```
@Composable
fun content() {
    return Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(8.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
        Column {
            Text("Hello")
            Text("World")
        }
    }
}
```

source: https://www.rockandnull.com/jetpack-compose-fillmaxheight-fillmaxwidth/

Comment: Super nice solution. Basically the child requests as much space as the parent can offer, but the parent requests only the minimum space required for the biggest child

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Layout Composable or Modifier. You can measure the defining element first and then provide modified constraints to the dependent element. If you want to use this as a modifier you should add a size check for the list.

```kotlin
Layout(content = {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(width = 30.dp, height = 50.dp)
        .background(Color.Green))
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Color.Yellow)
            .fillMaxHeight()
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
}) { measurables: List<Measurable>, constraints: Constraints ->
    val heightDef = measurables[0].measure(constraints)
    val other = measurables[1].measure(
        constraints.copy(
            maxHeight = heightDef.height,
            maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth - heightDef.width)
    )
    layout(
        width = heightDef.width + other.width,
        height = heightDef.height
    ) {
        other.placeRelative(0,0)
        heightDef.placeRelative(other.width,0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I had not used Layout Composable yet, it seems very flexible and it surely comes in handy for complex design requirements. Still, I feel my specific case is too simple to require such amount and complexity of code, there really should be a simpler way of doing this using Row.

Comment: The only other approach you could investigate is Intrinsics. Sadly I do not know how to use them yet. There is a section inside the layout codelab.

Answer (score 1):

For height, instead of `fillMaxHeight`, just put

```
.height(vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).defaultHeight)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice trick, it may be useful. But ideally, I'd like to use something that works for other kinds of content as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here's the equivalent design implemented with ConstraintLayout:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestUi() {
    ConstraintLayout {
        val (box, image) = createRefs()

        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Yellow)
                .constrainAs(box) {
                    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                }
        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }

        Image(
            imageVector = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(image) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(box.end)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use constraintlayout, the trick is in this part of the code `height =Dimension.fillToConstraints`

```kotlin
  ConstraintLayout(){
        val (boxRef, imgRef) = createRefs()

        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Yellow)
                .constrainAs(boxRef){
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(imgRef.start)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }

        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }

        Image(imageVector = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),modifier=Modifier.constrainAs(imgRef){
            start.linkTo(boxRef.end)
            top.linkTo(parent.top)
            end.linkTo(parent.end)
        })
    }
```